# Displaying retrieved value in File when Editing

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a simple image system in CodeIgniter, in which I can add, edit and delete images
(CRUD operation on Images).

Screenshot is:
 [image]

When click on edit. then it goes to:

When I click on EDIT then it goes to:
[image]

Code for **Choose File** is:

```
<div class="row-fluid"> 
    <div class="span6 ">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Image</label>  
                 <div class="controls"> 
                      <input type="file" tabindex="4" class="default" required="required" name="image" />
                      <?php echo form_error('Image', '<p class="error">', '</p>'); ?>
                 </div>
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I tried value="selected one" but it don't work.

Here if you noticed then you will see that image name and Activate is shown from database, when I edit these **image name** and **Activate** or any one of them and then click on **update image** then it works fine, however information about image in **Choose file** are not showed and it is required that choose file.

e.g., when I only want to change name of image or activate/deactivate, and not change image, then how I should do it?  Is it possible that already existing value will choose by default just like **image name** or **activate**. If you people have any idea about this, then please guide me in this regard. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

we can not show value in choose image file ...
if this filled is required remove the required attribute
2nd below the choose image filed ... display the old image 
3rd when they submit the form then check if files is selected or not 
if image file is empty then it mean that they are not updating the image so make an array without the image index and update the record if files is selected then this mean that user selected new image and wants to update the image then make an array with image index and update the whole record